# How to populate a dictionary with XML Elements and Values?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, comparison

I want to populate 2 dictionaries with 2 XML-Files, storing the tags as keys and the node.text as values in Python.

I don't understand how to populate a dictionary through a loop with the help of nodes, since I am fairly new to Python (1 week) and I don't have too much programming experience (yet). I've tried to google it for the past 2 hours but couldn't find anything I could work with. 
My idea was to loop through the nodes, check if the tag is already a key in the dictionary and if not create a key. Afterwards I would add the values from each tag to the corresponding key.

My code so far

```py
# coding=utf-8
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


# Folgender Block schreibt die Daten in ein  Objekt

base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xml_file1 = os.path.join(base_path, "data\\file1.xml")
xml_file2 = os.path.join(base_path, "data\\file2.xml")

# Die Datei, dessen inhalt ergänzt wird
tree1 = et.parse(xml_file1)
root1 = tree1.getroot()

# Die Datei, dessen Inhalt mit File1 verglichen wird
tree2 = et.parse(xml_file2)
root2 = tree2.getroot()

# Dictionaries für die jeweiligen XML-Files
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

for node in tree1.findall('.//LISTDATA'):
    for snode1 in node.getchildren():
        #I don't know the code for this

for node in tree2.findall(".//DATA"):
    for snode2 in node.getchildren():
        #I don't know the code for this
```

The XML is fairly basic

```
<ROOT>
<LISTDATA>
<DATA1>0001</DATA1>
<DATA2>0002</DATA2>
</LISTDATA>
</ROOT>
```

I appreciate any incoming advice.

Comment: This question is about assigning values in a dict, not about XML parsing. Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<ROOT>
<LISTDATA>
<DATA1>0001</DATA1>
<DATA2>0002</DATA2>
</LISTDATA>
</ROOT>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {entry.tag: entry.text for entry in list(root.find('.//LISTDATA'))}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'DATA1': '0001', 'DATA2': '0002'}
```